# Case insensitive uniqueness validation in a Ruby Sequel.migration

Tags: ruby, migration, email-validation, sequel

I'm trying to figure out a good validation to use in my migration that will require case-insensitive uniqueness for user email addresses.  In short, I want something like `validate :email, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}` without having to convert everything to use Rails or ActiveRecord.  I could run emails through regexes but I don't like that solution.

I found a comment[1] saying you could use
`validates_unique(:email){ |ds| ds.opts[:where].args.map! { |x| Sequel.function(:lower, x)}; ds}`
but I don't understand what that code is doing and I don't want to use that code when I have no idea what that `ds` object is or what all is going on (why `map!`, does postgresql have a `Sequel.function` of `:lower`? ... probably, but I just don't know.)

[1] http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.sequel/6447

So I need one of two things answered:
1) How do I perform a case-insensitive uniqueness validation in a pure `Sequel.migration` (no ActiveRecord, no Rails)?
- OR -
2) If that code snippet I found online is actually what I want, what does it do & how does it work?  (What is the `ds` object and what does this validation do with my database?)

Comment: It seems like you are confusing how validations and indexing work and what migrations do.

Comment: No, I'm trying to add a database constraint.  You can do that (and I already have some) in my `Sequel.migration` object.  I'm just not quite sure how to do this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Tin Man mentioned, you are confusing validations and constraints.  You say you are trying to add a constraint and talk about `Sequel.migration`, but those have nothing to do with validations.

If you want to add a database constraint, you need to do something like this in a migration:

```
alter_table(:table){add_unique_constraint Sequel.function(:lower, :email)}
```

This is done so that the database doesn't allow duplicate emails in a case insensitive manner.

Validations are just for presenting nice error messages to the user.  They are run before saving so that instead of the database raising a exception (which is difficult to deal with), you get a nice error message.

Like that comment mentions, you can't use validates_unique for case insensitive lookups on case sensitive databases without a hack.  It would require that validates_unique accept an additional option (which may be added in the future).

If you don't want to use a hack like that, you'll have to do the validation manually:

```
dataset = model.where{|o| {o.lower(:email)=>o.lower(email)}}
dataset.exclude(pk_hash) unless new?
errors.add(:email, 'is already taken') unless ds.count == 0
```

In terms of what that hack does,  `ds` is a `Sequel::Dataset` instance that `validates_unique` uses to check for uniqueness.  If you do `validates_unique :email`, it'll be something like:

```
model.where(:email=>email)
# WHERE email = 'some email'
```

`ds.opts[:where]` extracts the where clause from that dataset, and transforms the arguments, wrapping them in SQL `lower` function calls, in order to transform the where clause so that it is similar to:

```
model.where{|o| {o.lower(:email)=>o.lower(email)}}
# WHERE lower(email) = lower('some email')
```

It's a hack as it only works if the model's dataset is not already filtered.

Comment: I see.  As I said, I didn't understand that code snippet I found, so I didn't realize that it was something else.  Thanks.

Comment: rake aborted!  
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("  
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD UNIQUE (lower("name"))  

I copy/pasted what you said and made it alter_table(:users).

Comment: Crap, I guess it's a postgres thing: http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/174177-alter-table-add-unique